# Change memoir sidecaption margin for correct oneside display

Tags: margins, memoir, enumerate, thesis, sidecap

I use a `memoir` class to write my thesis, and i don't know why i write all my text using the `twoside` option.

Now i need `oneside` option to print - yes, this is a silly situation :( - for impression, and all my margin settings are broken.

I want the same **assymmetric page** for all recto printed page, with sidecaption to the right for each page.

[image]

About `\sidecapmargin` Memoir class say that :

> the \sidecapmargin command controls the margin where the sidecaption will be placed. The possible values for *margin* are one of: left , right , inner , or outer . If left or right is specified the caption will go into the left or right margin. If inner or outer is specified then in a two sided document the caption will be on different sides of the typeblock according to whether it is a recto or verso page; **in a one sided document the caption margin is fixed. The left margin is the default.**

Using a class document with `oneside`, i want the `sidecaption` go to the right (and default is left as the manual of memoir say).

The `\overridescapmargin{ right }` work **for only ONE sidecaption at a time**. How can i automatize this to all sidecaption, because `\sidecapmargin{}` command is desactivated in `oneside` option.

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,oneside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,final]{microtype}
%\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{lipsum}

\checkandfixthelayout %or perhaps \checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% after \checkandfix......

\raggedbottom
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}


% SIDE CAPTION 
\newsubfloat{figure}{}
\newsubfloat{table}{}

\loosesubcaptions

\setsidecappos{t}

\strictpagecheck

\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\cleardoublepage

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{my first chapter}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \overridescapmargin{right}
  \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin
  this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin}[fig:S_VV1]
    \centering
   \includegraphics[]{example-image-c}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum  

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \overridescapmargin{right}
  \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin  this is a very long comment on the margin}[fig:S_VV2]
    \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \overridescapmargin{right}
  \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin
  this is a very long comment on the margin  this is a very long comment on the margin  this is a very long comment on the margin}[fig:S_VV3]
    \centering
   \includegraphics[]{example-image-b}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}


\chapter{my second chapter}
\lipsum    

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin  this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin this is a very long comment on the margin}[fig:S_VV4]
    \centering
   \includegraphics[]{example-image-a}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum    

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\appendix
\appendixpage

\chapter{my first appendix}
\lipsum    

\chapter{my second appendix}
\lipsum    

\end{document}
```

What i want in the MWE :

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the oneside option for print? This makes all pages have a the oddpage layout. Oneside has nothing to do with whether or not you print single or double sided.

Comment: Because of the binding ? And because my margin are not the same for each page on recto printing ? I want symetric layout but not the oddpage :)

Comment: I still do not understand what it is you want.

Comment: updated with image, hope that help

Comment: If your printer automatically prints both sides, page 2 will be on the back or page 1 and the binding area will be on the wrong side.  You may want to add blank pages (see \cleardoublepage) between.

Comment: @JohnKormylo For a thesis i ask for a recto only impression.

Comment: @daleif i find a way to get the correct layout with oneside, but i can't fix the sidecaption position on the margin (i want a right position). Any idea?

Comment: "I want less space on the inner margin, more on the outer margin, with symmetric page like any thesis printed only in recto." -- what total margins do you want on each side (including binding), and how wide should the side captions be? Not sure how to reconcile less/more space on each margin with symmetric pages.

Comment: each page are assymetric (more space in outer margin, less space in inner margin), but symmetric page by page comparaison (page 1 = page 2 = ... = page n layout) . Hope it's more clear ?

Comment: So not symmetric. You just want the same asymmetry on each page? Why do you need the `right` option for sidebar captions with single-sided printing? Since you seem to have answered the margins question, can you maybe clarify what remains? A properly minimal example would be a major help.

Comment: use `\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,openany]{memoir}`

Comment: i update thequestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical error in the `oneside` placement part.

This works better

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\m@mscapcheckregside}{%
    \if@twoside
      \checkoddpage
      \ifnum\m@mscapmarg<\@ne%      % left
        \scapmarglefttrue
      \else
        \ifnum\m@mscapmarg=\@ne%    % right
          \scapmargleftfalse
        \else
          \ifnum\m@mscapmarg=\tw@%  % outer
            \scapmarglefttrue
            \ifoddpage
              \scapmargleftfalse
            \fi
          \else%                  % inner
            \scapmargleftfalse
            \ifoddpage
              \scapmarglefttrue
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \else%     oneside
    % left and inner should be the same
    % right and outer should be the same
    \ifcase\m@mscapmarg\relax% 0
      \scapmarglefttrue
    \or% 1
      \scapmargleftfalse
    \or% 2
      \scapmargleftfalse
    \or% 3
      \scapmarglefttrue
    \fi
\fi}

\makeatother
```

In `oneside` we set `left=inner` and `right=outer`. The version in current `memoir` sets `left=right` and `inner=outer`.

It will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Great news :) Is there a way to give more space to the right outer margin for sidecaption ? (for example like in two side )

Comment: Not understood. You can just set `\sidecapwidth`

Comment: Using `\setlength\sidecapwidth{<length of your choice>} ` i suppose, but how can i get the outer margin correct <length> ? Like the image

Comment: You cannot. The side caption *is* placed in the margin regardless of the size of the image. Other packages may provide similar functionality and does this differently. A better solution is on my TODO list, but is not going to be added any time soon.

Comment: Using your hack plus `\checkandfixthelayout` and `\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}`
, and by replacing `oneside` by `openany` i have the good layout. Don't know why.